# Install pytorch before importing in setup.py of another package in a single shot or instruction

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, torch, requirements.txt

I have a project that makes use of certain C package. Building the package is done as below in a setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup
import torch
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension
    setup(
        name='iou3d',
        ext_modules=[
            CUDAExtension('iou3d_cuda', [
                'src/iou3d.cpp',
                'src/iou3d_kernel.cu',
            ],
            extra_compile_args={'cxx': ['-g'],
                                'nvcc': ['-O2']})
        ],
        cmdclass={'build_ext': BuildExtension})
```

Now this is being setup correctly if I already have pytorch installed in my environment.

But if I am doing a fresh install on a clean environment using requirements.txt, and I want to install everything in one shot by `pip install -r requirements.txt` I am not sure how can I get to install pytorch first to be able to import it in the  setup.py.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: For this usage `torch` must be installed before `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Possible solutions: 1) distribute binary wheels (for as many platforms as possible), this allows the users to install precompiled versions without running `setup.py`; 2) switch to [`pyproject.toml`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pyproject.toml), it installs build dependencies before runtime dependencies, just declare `torch` as a build dependency.